# Can I run the same app simultaneously with two users?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, multi-user

In Android 5.0, can the same app run simultaneously under multiple users?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should be possible with multiple user profiles.

Comment: Are they actually running simultaneously?  Keeping apps running for an absent user seems that a luxury that a resource-limited phone can't afford (or shouldn't if you want your battery to last more than an hour).

Comment: If the app supports continuing in the background, then yes. Look at the running apps and there will be an entry for each other user. (currently, my Nexus7 only shows google services, but the secondary users have no apps)